# Electrostatic potential created by a relativistic bounded electron (i.e a 4-spinor)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrostatics, dirac-equation

Let's take the Gordon solution of the central field Dirac equation for the Hydrogen atom and look at [the wave functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen-like_atom#1S_orbital).

There is bounded functions inside the spinor, which represents here the full eigenstate of the electron (4 parts), like the electron bounded to the nucleus, perfectly logical. Then we can define an electrostatic potential with this spinor $\boldsymbol{\Psi}$ like:

$$ \Delta V(\boldsymbol{r}) = - q \epsilon_0 \vert \boldsymbol{\Psi}(\boldsymbol{r}) \vert^2 $$

My question is: in which physical topic did you see a Poisson's equation associated to a 4-spinor field ? This reminds us [Hartree potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartree_equation#Hartree_derivation), but I have never seen a Poisson's equation involving a 4-spinor as a source distribution, so I ask if anyone did. I am working on this topic for a conference, to adapt non-relativistic computations to relativistic ones.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding your question, you want the four potential of a charged dirac particle specifically while it's bound in another potential or a free dirac particle?

Comment: The hydrogen atom is an electron (4-spinor distribution) and a proton (approximated by a scalar 3D Dirac distribution). I do not want the "4-potential" $(\Phi/c, \boldsymbol{A})$ in particular... just the scalar part $\Phi/c$ which is the "classical" (the real infact...) electrostatic part. My question is: do you have seen a Poisson's equation like this involving the scalar part of the Dirac four current $\vert \Psi \vert^2$ ? If you have a full version involving 4-potential $(\Phi/c, \boldsymbol{A})$ and 4-current (Dirac current build with gamma matrices), it can interrest me also.

Comment: I see, there are more than one solution to the hydrogen atom, the usual is the Schrödinger formulation not involving spinors while there is also a dirac solution which will of course have your relativistic treatment.

Comment: Thanks Triatticus, so it does not shock you to calculate the bounded electron electrostatic field. So this formula can be applied. If you are interrested I can show you the topic I work on at the moment. It works for Schrodinger equation, but I have to prove it for Helium atom with the Dirac equation.